# MS Access confusing inner join failing

Tags: vba, ms-access

Okay I am confused…But that’s me easily confused.

I have a table.  tblPartDrawing.

This table has three columns being PartDrawingID, Part and PartDrawing(Path).

Column Part is linked to tlkupPart.  tlkupPart has PartID, PartNumber, PartDescription and PartThread in it.  The link is on PartID in the table structure.

I have created a look up from tblPartDrawing.Part to tlkupPart.PartID with the following SQL code:

```
SELECT tlkupPart.PartID, [PartNumber] & " " & [PartDescription] AS Expr1,tlkupPart.PartNumber
FROM tlkupPart
ORDER BY tlkupPart.PartNumber;
```

As I read this, and perhaps I am missing something here this means PartID is the stored value in the Part column of tblPartDrawing.Part

However when I ask SQL to produce the following:

```
SELECT tblPartDrawing.PartDrawingID, tblPartDrawing.Part, tblPartDrawing.Drawing, tlkupPart.PartNumber, tlkupPart.PartDescription, tlkupPart.PartThread
FROM tblPartDrawing INNER JOIN tlkupPart ON tblPartDrawing.Part = tlkupPart.PartID;
```

It is throwing a Type Mismatch error.  Clearly I am missing something, but I cant see what.  Anyone else see the issue here?

Comment: Is PartID an autonumber field? Is Part a number (Long Integer) field?

Comment: Yes.  That's what is confusing me.  Part Number is a Short Text field as it contains P and then a number.  PartID is what I am using as key for both fields.

Comment: If saving PartID (autonumber primary key) into Part (long integer) as foreign key, join should work. Apparently, this is not what is actually happening. I NEVER build lookup fields in tables. I build comboboxes on forms.

Answer (score 0):

If Part Number is a Short Text field (as it contains P), then PartID should be a text field, so you can join both fields and not get a "Type Mismatch" error.